# I keep getting a "self" is not defined error

Tags: python-2.7, self

Im trying to add a media file, so that when you press the key a is plays and you let go it stops, any help would be appreciated!

I get the error code self is not defined and I just need a point the right direction.

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import sys
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)

class MyGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize a new game"""
        pygame.init()

        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        #Load resources
        sound = pygame.mixer.music.load("a.mp3")
```

I keep getting a self is not defined error here

```
        #use a black background
        self.bg_color = 0, 0, 0

        #Setup a timer to refresh the display FPS times per second
        self.FPS = 30
        self.REFRESH = pygame.USEREVENT+1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.REFRESH, 1000//self.FPS)

        # Now jusr start waiting for events
        self.event_loop()

    def event_loop(self):
        """Loop forever processing events"""
        while 1 < 2:
            event = pygame.event.wait()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_A:
                sound.play()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_A:
                sound.stop()

            elif event.type == self.REFRESH:
                # time to draw a new frame
                self. draw()
                pygame.display.flip()

            else:
                pass #an event we dont handle

    def draw(self):
        """Updating the display"""
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)


MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Post the full Error traceback please

Comment: does the error message point to a line number?

Comment: The error will tell you exactly what line it's on.  Also, I'm expecting "Invalid syntax", not "self is not defined".

Comment: Minor style note: `while True:` is valid in Python when you want to loop forever

Comment: is the second block of code a continuation of the first block? is there anything between them that you didn't post?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing tabs and spaces.  This confuses Python about how far code is indented: your `self.bg_color = 0, 0, 0` line isn't as indented as you think it is.  Looking at your raw code:

```
'class MyGame(object):'
'\tdef __init__(self):'
'\t\t"""Initialize a new game"""'
'\t\tpygame.init()'
'\t\t'
'\t\tself.width = 800'
'\t\tself.height = 600'
'\t\tself.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))'
'\t\t'
'\t\t#Load resources'
'        sound = pygame.mixer.music.load("a.mp3")'
'\t\t#use a black background'
'        self.bg_color = 0, 0, 0'
```

Note the absence of tabs in two of the last four lines.

Use `python -tt your_program_name.py` to confirm this, and switch to using four spaces for indentation.  Most editors allow you to configure this.